# Replace N characters from a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace all `+` occurrences on this string:

```
agheuhfu3r3wogfjnsdnvv++3fefda+3zcvfsdf342rsdff3+fwef
```

with this character: `*`

What I wrote is that and it replaces only the first occurrence

```
var str = "agheuhfu3r3wogfjnsdnvv++3fefda+3zcvfsdf342rsdff3+fwef"; 
var res = str.replace('+', '*');
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: You can do this 2 ways:
1. str.replace(/\+/g, '*');

2. str.split('+').join('*');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Regular expression`:`str.replace(/\+/g, '*')` which replaces all the `+` symbols with `*` where `g` is global modifier.

```js
var str = "agheuhfu3r3wogfjnsdnvv++3fefda+3zcvfsdf342rsdff3+fwef"; 
var res = str.replace(/\+/g, '*');
console.log(res);
```

Take a tour in regular expression from here [MDN JS's Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 1):

replace() takes a regular expression pattern.

If you are replacing a value (and not a regular expression), only the first instance of the value will be replaced. To replace all occurrences of a specified value, use the global (g) modifier

```
var res = str.replace(/\+/g, '*');
```